# SQL how to check prefix in cell with two prefixes

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am learning SQL and I have a table where there are certain cells with two prefixes like this :

```
example1(cell) : R:8days; U:5$;
example2(cell) : R:8days;
example3(cell) : U:5$;
```

I want to check for that `U:5$` after the first prefix, as I know how to check for prefix `R:8days;`. So I need to check for `U:5$` and then make a new column in table.

My code looks like this:

```
;with cte as (
select
Employer, AmountPayd, AmountPayd as Payd
from data
where TipeOfTransaction like 'Offline Prepaid%' AND Note like '%R:8%' **HERE I WANT TO CHECK FOR PREFIX NR2. 'U:5$' AND MAKE NEW COLUMN FOR WHICH EMPLOYER HAS U:5$ NOTE.**
)
select
Employer,
     [4.00] = ISNULL([4.00],0)
    ,[5.00] = ISNULL([5.00],0)
    ,[9.00] = ISNULL([9.00],0)
    ,[10.00] = ISNULL([10.00],0)
    ,[15.00] = ISNULL([15.00],0)
    ,[Sum] =ISNULL([4.00],0) + ISNULL([5.00],0) + ISNULL([9.00],0) + ISNULL([10.00],0) + ISNULL([15.00],0)
    from cte
    pivot (
    sum(AmountPayd) for Payd in ([4.00],[5.00],[9.00], [10.00], [15.00], [20.00]))pvt;
```

Comment: The technique you need is called string splitting.  There are lots of questions on [SO that can show you how to do this](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=sql+string+splitter).  But I would recommend you change your table design instead.  Storing multiple values in one cell is a bad idea.  It works against the design principles that underpin SQL.  Each column should be dedicated to one purpose.

Comment: I know that, but I only wondered if I can do it like this, thank you for you answer.

Comment: There are a few different ways to achieve this.  But my personal favourite is to use a [tally table](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/dwainsql/2014/03/27/tally-tables-in-t-sql/).  These blogs talk about the approach: [SQL Server Central](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/) and [SQL Performance](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings).

Answer (score 1):

This?

```
select
  Employer, AmountPayd, AmountPayd as Payd,
  CASE WHEN Note like '%R:8%;%U:5$%' THEN 'U:5' END U5Note
from data
where TipeOfTransaction like 'Offline Prepaid%' AND Note like '%R:8%'
```

Comment: yes maybe something like this but i want to do U5Note in second column and want to fill the column with 5 where employer had that note written

Comment: Add desired output for sample data provided to your question.

Answer (score 1):

(I've corrected some mistakes in column names and refactored the query.)

I believe, you are looking for something like this:

```
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT
        Employer,
        AmountPaid,
        Paid
    FROM Data
    LEFT JOIN (VALUES (4, 5, 9, 10, 15, 20)) V(Paid)
        ON Note LIKE '%U:' + CAST(Paid AS VARCHAR(10)) + '$;%'
    WHERE TypeOfTransaction LIKE 'Offline Prepaid%'
        AND Note LIKE '%R:8%'
)
SELECT
    Employer,
    ISNULL([4.00], 0) AS [4.00],
    ISNULL([5.00], 0) AS [5.00],
    ISNULL([9.00], 0) AS [9.00],
    ISNULL([10.00], 0) AS [10.00],
    ISNULL([15.00], 0) AS [15.00],
    ISNULL([4.00] + [5.00] + [9.00] + [10.00] + [15.00], 0) AS Sum
FROM CTE
PIVOT( SUM(AmountPaid)
    FOR Paid IN ([4.00],[5.00],[9.00], [10.00], [15.00], [20.00])) PVT;
```